# Time Reversal in Euclidean Spacetime - unitary or antiunitary?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, fermions, time-reversal-symmetry, wick-rotation

**(pre-request)** We know that **time reversal operator** $T$ is an **anti-unitary operator** in Minkowsi Spacetime. i.e.

$$
T z=z^*T
$$
where the complex number $z$ becomes its complex conjugate. See, for example, Peskin and Schroeder ``An Introduction To Quantum Field Theory'' p.67 Eq (3.133).

---

**(Question)** Is **Euclidean time reversal operator** $T_E$ an **unitary operator**, i.e.

$$
T_E z=z T_E \;\;\;(?)
$$

or an **anti-unitary operator** in Euclidean Spacetime? Why is necessarily that or why is it necessarily not that? **Or should $T_E$ be an unitary operator like Parity $P$ instead?**

However, here see the attempt of a [PRL paper, Euclidean continuation of the Dirac fermion](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v65/i16/p1983_1)
 where time reversal $T_E$ is given by, on page 3:
$$
T_E z=z^*T_E \;\;\;(?)
$$ 
$T_E$ is still an **anti-unitary operator**!

It seems to me if one consider Euclidean spacetime, the Euclidean signature is the same sign, say $(-,-,-,-,\dots)$, then **Parity $P$** acts on the space is equivalent to the **Euclidean time reversal operator $T_E$** acts on Euclidean time (which is now like one of the spatial dimensions). So **shouldn't $T_E$ be an unitary operator as Parity $P$?**

---

[Other Refs]

i. Please, you may read, [an earlier Phys.SE question here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79765/), probably is poorly formulated, so cannot draw the efforts of people to answer the question. Here let me try an easier way and focus on one issue only.

ii. Osterwalder-Schrader (OS) approach, and [``A continuous Wick rotation for spinor fields and supersymmetry in Euclidean space''](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9611043) by Peter van Nieuwenhuizen, Andrew Waldron.

Comment: Starting with $Tz = z^*T$, and assuming $T = iT_E$, this would give $(iT_E)z = z^*(iT_E)$, that is $i(T_Ez) = (z^*i)T_E$, that is $(T_Ez) = -i(z^*i)T_E$, that is $T_Ez =z^*T_E$

Comment: Thanks Trimok, this can be an mathematical answer for a logical reason; I am sure that is what have been done in wick rotating with fermion fields. So even if Euclidean spacetime seemly treat spatial and euclidean-time the same in the signature/metric sense, but when the fermion gets involved, it will still tell the difference between ``euclidean-time'' and the ``remained space''? Simply by this anti-unitary property?

Comment: I suppose there exist more rigorous explanations for your question. But a point is that the real space-time is Minkowskian, so analytic continuation in Euclidean space-time does not mean that we forget all the properties and behaviours linked to the real Minkowskian space-time, and its Lorentz representations (the particles). Of course, all this  could be very subtle...